# Previous class runs over again when we run testcases using testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-annotation-test

I have 2 class which I'm running through **`TestNG`**, class A has 2 methods and class B has one method but when I run the suite of class A and B through **`TestNG`**, It runs like, class A method 1 & 2 will run and with class B it's method runs and method of class A also runs again y?

Answer (score 0):

Check your  tag in testNG.xml file, it should be like:

```
<classes>
     <class name="A"/>
     <class name="B"/>
</classes>
```

You can post you testNG.xml file code as it will be easy to identify the issue.